# GetAwaiter() Method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, simple.odata

I have a top level function like this

```
          var results = await client
                .For(x.Offices)
                .Select(x.NumberOfFlores, x.Hight)
                .QueryAsync();
```

client is my own function that does a bunch of stuff. (Not the same as ODataClient Client class)

The result of `QueryAsync()` returns a custom class. This class has several parameters, one of which is queryResults. This class has a `GetAwaiter()` function, which never works properly.

```
public async Task GetAwaiter()
{
        await queryResults;
}
```

`queryResults` is an object of type  `Task<IEnumerable<ODataEntry>>`

What i want it to do is wait for the queryResults to execute, so than i can use it in the form `results.QueryResults`

However, i get this error after the "await queryResults"

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]'
>   to type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion'.

The `getAwaiter` function does execute, but i get an error as soon as i return from it.

I have tried a bunch of different things, but nothing works. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have your own `GetAwaiter` method? I think you need to step back a bit and ask yourself what you're trying to do. `Task`s are not awaiters, they are awaitables - just make your `QueryAsync` return a `Task`, and be done with it.

Comment: I cant do that because i need to return multiple things, not just a single Task. Hence, i made a Data-Structure, which contains several parameters. One of them is this Task, which needs to wait for the top level class to call "await"

Comment: @user2824991 Then you should be awaiting the `Task` property of that object, rather than the object itself.

Comment: A Task is not a return "value". Its a pointer to a method block on that lives on "any" thread (including the current thread). Period. It could be executing currently, it could have already executed, or in some cases not even executed yet. 
Given that, if  your async method returns "multiple things", then use Task<T>, and create a class or structure to hold your "multiple things". Use that Type as the T in Task<T>.

Comment: Wait a minute...Unless you've excessively edited your "code" for your GetAwaiter (not a good name BTW) method, have you noticed you're missing a "return" statement? In fact, that error message pretty much tells you this. Specifically this "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]'". You've written a void method (no return value). The fact that the method begins with "Get" tells me this is not the intention.

Answer (score 3):

`Task` is not an awaiter, it's an awaitable. That means that you can't return it from your `GetAwaiter` method - it doesn't fit the contract.

If you really want to go this road (and I really don't see the point), make sure your `GetAwaiter` actually returns an awaiter:

```
public TaskAwaiter<IEnumerable<ODataEntry>> GetAwaiter()
{
  return queryResults.GetAwaiter();
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to return a task of a different type, you need to return a task of a different type - there's no way around it. This reeks of bad design, but you can do something like this:

```
public TaskAwaiter<Tuple<YourObject, IEnumerable<ODataEntry>>> GetAwaiter()
{
  return 
    queryResults
    .ContinueWith(t => Tuple.Create(this, t.Result))
    .GetAwaiter();
}
```

This will return both your query object and the results as two separate properties of the tuple - of course, you can use whatever other type you'd like. However, I'd still strongly suggest rethinking your current design - it looks exactly like the kind that's going to give you headaches in a year or two.

Comment: I dont want to return the task. I have a custom class with multiple properties that i want accessed. One of these is the said `Task`. When you call `await` in the top most class, i want the `Task` in my custom class to be processed.

Comment: @user2824991 You can wrap whatever other value you need returned - check my update. I just fixed your `GetAwaiter` code, because it simply didn't make any sense - it must return an awaiter, while you were trying to return a task. In fact, you could easily make your whole query object an awaiter, but that's just digging deeper into trouble.