# An async method cannot return any type that has an accessible GetAwaiter method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

It says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types):

> Async methods can have the following return types:
>
> - [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task), for an async method that performs an operation but returns no
>   value.
> - [`Task <TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1), for an async method that returns a value.
> - `void`, for an event handler.
> - Starting with C# 7.0, **any type that has an accessible `GetAwaiter`
>   method**. The object returned by the `GetAwaiter` method must implement
>   the [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ICriticalNotifyCompletion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.icriticalnotifycompletion)
>   interface.
> - Starting with C# 8.0, [`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1), for an async method that
>   returns an *async stream*.

**Question**. How to understand the phrase: *"Asynchronous methods can have the following return types: ... any type that has an accessible `GetAwaiter` method"*, if the actual is not?

This code is not working:

```cs
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

async A Method() //Error CS1983 The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task<T>, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, or IAsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    await new A();
}

class A
{
    public TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter()
    {
        return new TaskAwaiter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GetAwaiter() Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997445/getawaiter-method)

Comment: @TimRoberts, It doesn't look like it has anything to do with it.

Comment: Defining a method `async Something Method`, C# needs to transform your method into a coroutine state machine. Your `Something` needs to be a task-like type. Using `await Something` the something needs a `GetAwaiter`. These are two different problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The summary docs are a bit confusing. `GetAwaiter` is insufficient to be used as a return type; `GetAwaiter` is more about `await` than `async`.

The [more detailed docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#generalized-async-return-types-and-valuetasktresult) clarify:

> In addition, the type returned from the GetAwaiter method must have the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderAttribute attribute.

The `AsyncMethodBuilder` attribute gives the compiler sufficient information to actually build and control the return type instance from the async state machine.

`TaskAwaiter<T>` [does not have](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/c6af4cfc8b625851b91823d9be746c4f7abdc667/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs#L54) this attribute. It doesn't normally need it because task return types are "grandfathered in" and treated specially by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out by trial and error. All the same, this is more about the await keyword. But I decided to clarify here.