# What the async and await keywords apply to?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm completely confused.

It says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types):

> Async methods can have the following return types:
>
> - [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task), for an async method that performs an operation but returns no
>   value.
> - [`Task <TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1), for an async method that returns a value.
> - `void`, for an event handler.
> - Starting with C# 7.0, any type that has an accessible `GetAwaiter`
>   method. The object returned by the `GetAwaiter` method must implement
>   the [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ICriticalNotifyCompletion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.icriticalnotifycompletion)
>   interface.
> - Starting with C# 8.0, [`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1), for an async method that
>   returns an *async stream*.

- **Question 1**. Why write about tasks if `Task` and `Task<Result>` fit the "GetAwaiter" criterion?
- **Question 2**. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73439341/an-async-method-cannot-return-any-type-that-has-an-accessible-getawaiter-method) I got the answer that the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` point is more about **await**. Then what about everything else? Can someone clearly explain what each keyword applies to without big examples?

  **What types can return async methods - list or criteria? And what types can the await keyword or their criteria apply to**?

Examples of answers how I would like:

---

Keyword **async** applicable for return values (async methods can return values): type1, type2, typeN, or any type with specific characteristics (for example ... some characteristics).

Keyword **await** applicable for awaitable types: type1, type2, typeN, or type with specific characteristics (for example contains `GetAwaiter`).

---

- **Question 3**. Speaking of void we mean only the return value of the async method. Can void be the awaitable type? Can someone give an example of a void awaiting?

Comment: _"Can someone clearly explain what each keyword applies to without ten-story examples?"_ - **haha** _no_. That's impossible.

Comment: _"Keyword `async` applicable for return values"_   <-- This is incorrect. The `async` modifier is only applied to methods (functions) and it tells the C# compiler to _allow_ the use of the `await` operator within that method (which in-turn causes the compiler to compile the method to those the weird state-machine gubbins you see in ILSpy). It has nothing to do with return values.

Comment: _"Speaking of `void` we mean only the return value of the async method, is `void` not the expected type?"_ <-- No. The rule-of-thumb is to **never use `async void`** - the only reason that the C# compiler _lets you_ have `async void` methods is because of historical legacy reasons with WinForms and WPF (as they _needed_ to keep on using the `EventHandler<T>` delegate type, but `EventHandler<T>` is a `void`-returning delegate). IMO it really shouldn't be allowed at all.

Comment: _"Why write about tasks if `Task `and `Task<Result>` fit the `GetAwaiter` criterion?"_ - the `Task` type _predates_ the `async`/`await` feature: `Task` originally shipped with the _Task Parallel Library_ (`ParallelFor`, etc) in .NET Framework 4.0 in 2010, but `async`/`await` wasn't added until .NET Framework 4.5 in 2012. And support for the `GetAwaiter` "pattern" (protocol? interface? duck-type?) wasn't added until C# 7.0 which wasn't until 2017 - and even so, `Task` and `Task<TResult>` are part of .NET, whereas using `GetAwaiter` means doing a lot of reinventing-the-wheel 99% of the time.

Comment: @Dai, Good. What types can return async methods - list or criteria? And what types can the await keyword or their criteria apply to?

Comment: _"What types can return asynchronous methods"_ - I think you mean "what types can be returned from `async` methods?"

Comment: @Dai, yes. And what types can the await keyword or their criteria apply to.

Comment: `await` can be used with any type that implements `GetAwaiter`, but in-practice the only types that matter (off the top-of-my-head) are `Task`, `Task<TResult>`, `ValueTask<T>`, and `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`

Comment: I know this is very pedantic, but you can apparently also `await` a `dynamic` expression.

Comment: @Dai, That is await is applicable by criterion - any type with public GetAwaiter and IAsyncEnumerable<T> for asynchronous use of foreach. What remains are the return types of async methods. Would you give a list or criteria? You can make an answer and I will count it.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: What do you mean by "ten-story examples"?

Comment: Regarding Q1: The `GetAwaiter` criterion explicitly applies to C#7 or greater, whereas `Task` and `Task<TResult>` can be used in older versions.

Comment: Can I get an answer point by point, cold and with types or criteria? Questions 2 and 3 are more of a concern. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why write about tasks if Task and Task fit the "GetAwaiter" criterion?

Probably because `Task/Task<Result>` will be used in 90% or so of all cases. It hints to a new developer to just use these types, and not try to implement a custom type for this, or spending extra time looking up the documentation.

> Question 2. Here I got the answer that the IAsyncEnumerable point is more about await. Then what about everything else? Can someone clearly explain what each keyword applies to without ten-story examples?

**async** is used to tell the compiler to rewrite the method into a state machine, so that different parts of the method can be run at different times. If the method returns anything, this needs to be wrapped in something that allow the caller to use the result when it is actually produced.

**await** is used in an async method suspend execution of the method until the awaited value is available. I.e. it marks where the compiler will split the method into the different sections.

I think you are making this more complicated then it needs to be:

- Use `Task` when you do not need to return a value
- Use `Task<Result>` when you return a value
- Use `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` when producing a sequence of values asynchronously. I.e. each value is produced by a separate network/Database call. Contrast with `Task<T[]>` when one IO call produces a sequence of values.
- Use ValueTask when you want to minimize overhead. See [Understanding the Whys, Whats, and Whens of ValueTask](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/)
- Use void when you are forced to. I.e. UI event handlers.
- Use a custom type when you have some special reason to. This should be quite rare, I would expect 99% of developers never to write any such implementation.

> Speaking of void we mean only the return value of the async method, is void not the expected type?

A normal non-async void method can actually produce two results:

1. Nothing
2. An exception

And the result is only produced once the method has reached its end. Awaiting a method returning a Task replicates this behavior. An async void method however does not. Since there is nothing to await, the caller have no way of knowing when, and if the method reaches its end. And exceptions may be lost, without anyone knowing it occurred. This is acceptable for things like UI events, after all, why does the UI system does not really care about what happens when a button is pressed, it is up to the developer to do things like handling exceptions. But in most other cases, `Task` should be used to represent a synchronous void-method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm especially gifted, so I'll clarify. Async method should usually return Task, Task<T>, ValueTask, ValueTask<T> and void, less often should return IAsyncEnumerable<T> and IAsyncEnumerator<T>. Await applies to awaitable objects which are typically Task, Task<T>, ValueTask, ValueTask<T>, more rarely IAsyncEnumerable<T>, and never void. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @NikVladi I would consider the more important thing is to know a bit about what is actually happening behind the scene when using asynchronous and multi threaded programming. So I would recommend reading some articles on the subject and doing some experimentation. Once you have some more background knowledge
selecting the appropriate return type should be fairly natural.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying to understand all the possible options and the purpose of their application. Void definitely not awaitable.